# Understanding the discretization of the Euler Top with Hirota-Kimura

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrable-systems

The Euler Top is the system $$\begin{cases}x_1' = \alpha_1 x_2 x_3 \\ x_2' = \alpha_2 x_3 x_1 \\ x_3' = \alpha_3 x_1 x_2\end{cases}$$

The HK discretization scheme is given by: [HK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaIhw.png)

I am reading this part of a paper:  [(Petrera2011)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdpun.png)

I want to figure out how $(6.4)$ is obtained exactly by replicating the calculation, but I get stuck. So far I have solved for $x_3^{\sim}$, but what I find doesn't look like it will lead me to what they have. Can anyone take a look?

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCGVJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You have an $x_3$ on the right side of the third discretized equation that should not be there. This right side is composed of $x_1$ and $x_2$ as in the ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it down systematically,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-hα_1x_3&-hα_1x_2\\
-hα_2x_3&1&-hα_2x_1\\
-hα_3x_2&-hα_3x_1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde x_1\\\tilde x_2\\\tilde x_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now apply Cramer's rule to get rational expressions for the solution. In a numerical implementation you would call a linear solver

Comment: It seems that error you mentioned really threw me off track. By the numerical implementation comment you mean to call a symbolic-solver function? I have Matlab so maybe I can do it with that and save myself time?

Comment: No, just the normal linear solver, in Matlab implemented via division operator `x_next=A\x`. You can of course use the symbolic facilities of Matlab or any other CAS to avoid to evaluate Cramer manually.